# How to change ManagedBy owner from one user to another one for 150+ groups using power shell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I would like to change the Active Directory Group tab ManagedBy user to another one. With PowerShell script, I exported the groups with the old owner (>150) to a csv file. Now I need to change the owner of those groups using the csv file as input.

I don`t have much experience with scripting, I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why tag all PowerShell versions you could find? What version(s) are yuo actually using? Also, show us what you have already tried, what failed, what error messages (if any) you received etc. We can help you with your code, but only if you show it..

Answer (score 0):

The task is very easy with PowerShell. You didn't show an example of the CSV data you exported so an example may not be exact.  However, I assume you exported the default output of `Get-ADGroup` it might look something like this

```
(Import-Csv C:\temp\managedBy.csv).DistinguishedName| Set-ADGroup -ManagedBy <NewManager's DN>
```

Note: I like to use the DistinguishedName for these things but samAccountName should also work.

```
(Import-Csv C:\temp\managedBy.csv).samAccountName | Set-ADGroup -ManagedBy <NewsamAccountName>
```

Note: Again with the assumption that your Csv data is a direct export `Get-ADGroups`'s output. You cannot pipe `Import-Csv` directly to `Get/Set-ADGroup` as the latter will have trouble determining which property to bind to the `-Identity` parameter.

However, I would point out you really don't need the intermediate Csv file.  You can query AD directly for groups managed by the old manager and pipe that to a command to change the owner.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "ManagedBy -eq '<OldOwner'sDN>'" |
Set-ADGroup -ManagedBy "<NewOwner'sDN"
```

Note: Again you may be able to get away with using the samAccountName instead of the DN.

Note: You can add the `WhatIf parameter to the` Set-ADGroup` command to preview what will happen before actually running it.